# Blurry image after using UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidynamicanimator

I'm using UIDynamicsAnimator with good results except that after the animations are done the image that have been pushed and bounced is blurry. Please help me.

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *someImage;

self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

self.gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.someImage]];
CGVector gravityDirection = {-1.0, 0.5};
[self.gravity setGravityDirection:gravityDirection];

self.collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.someImage]];
self.collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;

self.itemBehaviour = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.someImage]];
self.itemBehaviour.elasticity = 0.5;

[self.animator removeAllBehaviors]; // to avoid problems from the last behaviour animation

[self.collision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"barrier"
                               fromPoint:CGPointMake(444,0)
                               toPoint:CGPointMake(444,768)];

self.pushBehavior = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.someImage] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
self.pushBehavior.magnitude = 1.0f;
self.pushBehavior.angle = 0.0f;
[self.animator addBehavior:self.pushBehavior];

self.pushBehavior.pushDirection = CGVectorMake(1.0f, 0.0f)
self.pushBehavior.active = YES;

[self.animator addBehavior:self.itemBehaviour];
[self.animator addBehavior:self.collision];
[self.animator addBehavior:self.gravity];
```

Comment: what is a real size of the image in pixels? are the final location's coordinates whole numbers or fractions?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the image isn't on an exact point when the animation is done. I would sugest that you add a delegate and when the animation pauses you round the x and y for the image to the closest integer.

Comment: I solved the problem by adjusting the image size to even numbers of height and width. Maybe the problem was that UIDynamics needs both frame origin and view center to be exact points.